# Python - Performant Video stream buffer

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linked-list, video-streaming

How do I build a performant video stream buffer that I can do numpy array operations on?

This is my implementation currently - I just shift the previous array forward 1 frame and assign the last element to the current frame.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
status, frame = cap.read()
buffer = np.empty([100, frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1], frame.shape[2]])
i=0
total = 100
while i < total:
    if not i: 
        start = time.time()
    status, frame = cap.read()
    t = time.time()
    if i < total/2:
        buffer[i] = frame
    else:
        buffer[:-1] = buffer[1:]
        buffer[-1] = frame
    if i == total/2: 
        middle = t
    i += 1
    # Calculations on the buffer ommitted for brevity but include mean, std, etc.

stop = time.time()
print((middle-start)/(total/2))
print((stop-middle)/(total/2))
```

It takes about 350X longer to shift the array as opposed to simply assigning the values of a frame to an element of the array.  I know this is because I am shifting all the pointers in the array which is unnecessary and expensive. Keeping the frames in order is nice but not necessary.

Comment: If the order of frames to be stored in `buffer` is not important for the intended operations, you can store in a cyclic manner, i.e. 0,1,...99,0,1... and so on. So, I think it depends on the missing info on the  intended operations. Also, what's the significance of `middle`?

Comment: Could you further explain what your end goal is? OpenCV uses Numpy arrays to display images so you can directly perform numpy array operations on your `frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One surprisingly simple way to make a minor improvement to this is to use a Python List for the actual shifting/appending, then re-instantiate the buffer as a new NumPy array, like so:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import itertools
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
status, frame = cap.read()
buffer = np.empty([100, frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1], frame.shape[2]])
i=0
total = 100
middle = 0
while i < total:
    if not i: 
        start = time.time()
    status, frame = cap.read()
    t = time.time()
    if i < total/2:
        buffer[i] = frame
    else:
        list_buffer = [item for item in buffer[1:]]
        list_buffer.append(frame)
        buffer = np.asanyarray(list_buffer)
    if i == total/2: 
        middle = t
    i += 1
    # Calculations on the buffer ommitted for brevity but include mean, std, etc.

stop = time.time()
print((middle-start)/(total/2))
print((stop-middle)/(total/2))
```

On my machine that takes the second time total from 1.7 seconds down to about 1.36 seconds. Not a huge improvement, but not insignificant either (~20% speedup).

However, if we instead use the list_buffer in the whole loop to keep track of the contents of the buffer and simply do both our slicing and appending on *that*:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import itertools
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
status, frame = cap.read()
buffer = np.empty([100, frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1], frame.shape[2]])
i=0
total = 100
middle = 0
list_buffer = []
while i < total:
    if not i: 
        start = time.time()
    status, frame = cap.read()
    t = time.time()
    if i < total/2:
        buffer[i] = frame
        list_buffer.append(frame)
    else:
        list_buffer = list_buffer[1:]
        list_buffer.append(frame)
        buffer = np.asanyarray(list_buffer)
    if i == total/2: 
        middle = t
    i += 1
    # Calculations on the buffer ommitted for brevity but include mean, std, etc.

stop = time.time()
print((middle-start)/(total/2))
print((stop-middle)/(total/2))
```

suddenly our output looks like this:

```
>>> 0.08505516052246094
>>> 0.08459827899932862
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Reformatting the list as a numpy array costs very little.  The deque/linked list was not really any more efficient with 100 frames in the buffer.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import collections

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
i=0
buff_len = 100

# buffer = []                           #Standard list
# buffer = collections.deque()          #linked list 
status, frame = cap.read()              #numpy array - replaces the first frame once it reaches the last frame
buffer = np.empty([buff_len, frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1], frame.shape[2]])

times_through = 3
start = time.time()

while i < times_through*buff_len:
    t = time.time()
    status, frame = cap.read()
    # buffer.append(frame)              #list and linked list 
    buffer[i%(buff_len)] = frame        #numpy array 
    # if i >= buff_len:                 #list and linked list 
        # buffer.pop(0)                 #list  
        # buffer.popleft()              #linked list 
    if i == buff_len:
        full = t
    i += 1
    print(i, np.mean(buffer, dtype=np.int), int((time.time()-t)*100)/100.)
stop = time.time()
print((full-start)/(buff_len))
print((stop-full)/(buff_len*(times_through-1)))
print(len(buffer))
```

Results in seconds/frame:

```
# list
# 0.19624330043792726
# 0.3691681241989136

# linked list
# 0.19301403045654297
# 0.3468885350227356

# numpy Array 
# 0.316677029132843
# 0.30973124504089355
```